# jQuery and CSS min-height:100%

Tags: javascript, css

MY CSS:

```
body{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

MY JQ:

```
function abc(){
   var h_1 = jQuery('.top_menu_container').height();
   var h_2 = jQuery('.bottom_container').height();
   var sum = h_1 + h_2;
   var body_h = jQuery('body').height();

   jQuery('.s1_container').css('height',( body_h - sum ) + 'px');
}

setInterval(abc,1000);
```

And what is goind on... When "body" have min-height:100%; and I change widow width to for example less than 767px when body have overflow-y:visible , body height is bigger and bigger for every setInterval - it summed earlier height + current height. I need min-height for body because it has background

Comment: Without your HTML it is hard to figure out what is going on. Can you provide a snippet?

Comment: Why don't you use [JQuery's `resize()` event](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)?

Comment: No resize() because if someone open page on mobile there will be no resize event.

Answer (score 0):

What if just use vh? )

```
body {
    min-height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: any IE do not support it, even EDGE

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units
well, not really. where you've heard IE don't support it? Only 8th IE do not.

Comment: ok it work on IE but doesn't work in my example ... if I change window width and scroll for Y shows, jQuery('.s1_container).css('height',a+b) do not set value but add a+b to exist height value and site whole time increase.